# How to fit ARIMA model to seasonal streamflow data in R?

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data, forecasting, arima

In Canada we often do not have streamflow data during freezing months (Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb). How to fit the following code for gauges that has seasonal data(Data available from March 01-Oct31 for each year)?

I wrote the following code for a station that has continuous streamflow data (Jan 01- Dec 31) at daily time step. I am training the model by grabbing maximum value of each month over the period 1970-2018. The code, however, won't work for gauges that have seasonal streamflow data (data available from March 01- October 31 only)- that means I do not have for Nov, Dec, Jan Feb for the entire 1970-2018 period. I believe I have to play with the line where I am grabbing FlowData especially the start and Frequency stuff but Can't figure out what to do.

```
#########################
# General setup
###########################
setwd("G:/ARIMA_Model")
install.packages("fpp2")
library(fpp2)
library(tidyverse)
graphics.off() # close all open figures
rm(list=ls())  # clear workspace

MyData <- read.csv("Kamsack_April.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

#########################
# Grabbing maximum value in each month.
###########################
Monthly=MyData %>% select(year, month, day, Flow..m3.sec.) %>% 
  group_by(year, month) %>% 
  summarise(Max_Streamflow=max(Flow..m3.sec., na.rm = TRUE))

FlowData=ts(Monthly[,3], start = c(1970,01), frequency = 12) 

#########################
# Fit  ARIMA model
###########################

# ARIMA model fitting
Fit_ARIMA= auto.arima(FlowData,d=1,D=1, stepwise = TRUE, approximation = TRUE, trace = TRUE)
print(summary(Fit_ARIMA))
checkresiduals(Fit_ARIMA)


#########################
# Forecast for next six months
###########################
# Use the model to predict next 6 months
fcst=forecast(Fit_ARIMA, h=6)
```

Comment: Any suggestions and thoughts are welocme